# Possible to adjust character width?

Tags: beamer, listings, pdftex

I'm using `Beamer` and `lstlisting` to put some code in a presentation.

The character spacing feels a bit too wide to my eye. Is it possible to reduce it? I've tried searching on this SE but can't seem to see anything obvious.

EDIT:

This seems trivial but:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{A frame}
\begin{lstlisting}
the letters are too far apart
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add an example of what you mean?

Comment: Done, unless you want the complete file, \usepackage and all?

Comment: Try `\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fullflexible]` and tell whether it's better.

Comment: Thanks @egreg that is exactly what I wanted. Give it as an answer and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default setting of `listings` is to place each character in a box in order to ensure vertical alignment emulating terminal output.

However, this may not be nice when the default font is proportionally spaced. There are two solutions (actually one):

```
\lstset{columns=fullflexible}
```

in the document preamble will typeset in normal character boxes. However, usually listings are typeset with a monospaced font, so

```
\lstset{columns=fullflexible,basicfamily=\ttfamily}
```

will do both settings.

The key-value pair can also be specified on a local basis:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fullflexible,basicfamily=\ttfamily]
```

will apply the settings only to that `lstlisting` environment.

The key `keepspaces` will also avoid merging two spaces into one.